# Converting a Map Scale

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, maps

I need some guidance. I'm using an ESRI Base Map with Web Mercator projection(Wkid - 102110) in an web application using JavaScript. I'm trying to display the Map Scale as range on the map. I got the Map Scale using the map.getScale() function . Lets say the map Scale returned was 144447.638 - Does that mean 1 inch is equal to that many meters or do i have to do some kind of conversion.

I'm ultimately trying to show 1 inch equal to X miles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map.getScale()` method returns the `X` value in `1:X`, where 1 and X have the same unit. When you see a map scale of 144447.638, that's 1 map inch = 144447.638 real world inches (or 1 map meter = 144447.638 real world meters).

If you want to convert the unit of the second measurement to miles, just convert the `map.getScale()` value from `inches` to `miles`.

```
144447.638 inches * 1 foot / 12 inches * 1 mile / 5380 feet = 2.237416945477076 miles.
```